# How many group structures make $S^1$ a topological group?

Tags: group-theory, lie-groups, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups

Let $S^1$ be the subspace of $R^2$ given the usual topology. How many group structures make $S^1$ a topological group?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hint: Assume that $\times$ is the group operation that matches with complex multiplication restricted to the unit circle. Assume that $\phi:S^1\to S^1$ is any homeomorphism. Can you show that the operation $\cdot$ defined via
$$z_1\cdot z_2=\phi^{-1}(\phi(z_1)\times \phi(z_2))$$ turns $S_1$ into a topological group?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thank you , but are these the only group structures that make S1 a topological group ？

Comment: I don't know. That question is deeper.

Answer (score 9):

Up to conjugating by homeomorphisms, the only topological group structure on $S^1$ is the standard one.  Here is the lowest-tech proof of this fact I can see.

Suppose we have a continuous group structure on $S^1$; we may assume its identity is $1\in S^1\subset\mathbb{C}$.  This group structure then lifts to a group structure on the universal cover $\mathbb{R}\to S^1$ ($x\mapsto \exp(2\pi i x)$), such that translation by preimages of the identity correspond to deck transformations.  Thus we may assume we have a continuous group operation $*$ on $\mathbb{R}$ which has the property that if $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $n*x=n+x$.  We will show that $*$ is conjugate to addition by a homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that commutes with the map $x\mapsto x+1$; it then follows that our group operation on $S^1$ is conjugate to the standard group structure by the corresponding homeomorphism $S^1\to S^1$.

First, fix any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and consider the map $R_x(y)=y*x$.  This is a homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, so it is either increasing or decreasing.  Since $R_x(n)=n+x$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, we find that $R_x$ must be increasing.  That is, $y<z$ implies $y*x<z*x$.

Now consider the map $f(x)=x*x$ from $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.  We know that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=2$, so by the intermediate value theorem there is some $x_1\in (0,1)$ such that $f(x_1)=1$.  There is then some $x_2\in (0,x_1)$ such that $f(x_2)=x_1$, and so on.  In this way we can find elements $x_n$ which generate a subgroup $Q$ which is (algebraically) isomorphic to the dyadic rationals $D$ via a map $\varphi:D\to Q$ such that $\varphi(1/2^n)=x_n$.  Furthermore, repeatedly applying the implication $y<z\implies y*x<z*x$ gives that $\varphi$ is order-preserving.

Furthermore, the elements $x_n$ are positive and decreasing, so they converge to some value $y$.  This $y$ will be a fixed point of $f$; i.e., $y=y*y$, so $y=0$.

I now claim that $Q$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.  Since $1\in Q$ and $1*x=1+x$ for all $x$, it suffices to show $Q$ is dense in $[0,1]$.  Now note that the group operation $*$ is uniformly continuous on the compact set $[0,1]\times[0,1]$.  In particular, this implies that for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that if $0\leq x\leq\delta$, then $y\leq y*x\leq y+\epsilon$ for all $y\in [0,1]$.  Since the numbers $x_n$ converge to $0$, this means that if $n$ is sufficiently large then consecutive powers of $x_n$ in $[0,1]$ differ by at most $\epsilon$.  Since these powers are elements of $Q$ and range from $0$ to $1$, this means every number between $0$ and $1$ is within $\epsilon/2$ of an element of $Q$.  Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, this means $Q$ is dense in $[0,1]$ and hence in $\mathbb{R}$.

Thus we have an order-preserving group-isomorphism $\varphi:D\to Q$ from $D$ to a dense subset $Q$ of $\mathbb{R}$.  Since $\mathbb{R}$ is the Dedekind-completion of both $D$ and $Q$, $\varphi$ extends uniquely to an order-isomorphism $\bar{\varphi}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$.  By continuity of the group operations on both sides, $\bar{\varphi}$ is also a group-isomorphism.  It follows that $\bar{\varphi}$ is an isomorphism of topological groups from $(\mathbb{R},+)$ to $(\mathbb{R},*)$.  Furthermore, $\bar{\varphi}$ is the identity on $\mathbb{Z}$ and $x*1=x+1$, so $\bar{\varphi}$ commutes with the map $x\mapsto x+1$.

Answer (score 5):

It seems the following. Let $G$ be an abelian topogical group whose space is $S^1$. Then $G$ is a compact locally connected second countable topological group, so by [Pon, Th. 49] it is topologically isomorphic to a direct product $(S^1)^r Z$, where $r\le\omega$ and the group $Z$ is finite. Since $G$ is connected and has dimension $1$, we have $r=1$ and the group $Z$ is trivial, so the group $G$ is topologically isomorphic to the group $S^1$.

*References*

[Pon] Lev S. Pontrjagin, *Continuous groups*, 2nd ed., M., (1954) (in Russian).

Comment: Surely that theorem has an "abelian" hypothesis somewhere.

Comment: @EricWofsey Oh, yes, it was written at the beginning of the chapter.

Answer (score 2):

If $S^1$ is a topological group, it is, in a unique way, a Lie group in a compatible way, and with that structure, isomorphic to the usual $S^1$ by the structure theory of compact abelian Lie groups.