# More circle groups

Tags: group-theory

Given that $$S=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$$ is a group under usual multiplication of complex numbers. Can you think of another appropriate $r>0$ and a binary operation $*$ on $T$ so that $\langle T,*\rangle$ becomes a group, where $$T=\{z\in \mathbb{C}:|z|=r\}$$ is a group?

With the same binary operation, I have come to understand that another circle group won't exist.

Comment: You can do silly things, since we can just transport _any_ group structure along your favorite bijection between $T$ and any other set of size continuum. In this way, we can make $(T,\ast) \cong \mathbb{R}$, $(T,\star) \cong \mathbb{C}$, etc.

Comment: Of course, you might contest that these aren't "natural" to the fact that $T$ is a circle. One way to make that intuition precise is to require that the group operations be _continuous_ with respect to the usual topology on $T$. If you make this requirement, then the usual group structure is basically the only one. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1498307/655547) for some proofs.

Comment: Can you think of a concrete sort of such a binary operation?

Comment: Sure -- If $f : T \to \mathbb{R}$ is your favorite bijection, then define $x * y \triangleq f^{-1}(f(x) + f(y))$, and you'll find $f$ becomes an isomorphism $(T, *) \cong (\mathbb{R}, +)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest option:
$$
u*v=\frac{uv}{r}.
$$